# Не могу отключить режим "ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY" в Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

Возникла ошибка в sql, связанная с режимом ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY. Хотел отключить, но не работает:

```
DB::statement("SET SESSION sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));");
// тут все ОК, ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY больше нет в списке: STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
$query->select(/* мой запрос, выдающий ..ORDER BY clause is not in SELECT list.. */)
```

но выключения 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY' по факту не случилось.
Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Надо не режим менять, а запрос переписывать, чтобы он не приводил к ошибке.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте в конфиге database.php у соединения проставить параметр `strict` в  `false`:

```
'connections' => [
    'mysql' => [
        'strict' => false,
    ]
]
```